# Inclusion of POCO Header Files in Objective C++ .mm file results in Compilation Error on Xcode 6

Tags: c++, xcode, poco, objective-c++, poco-libraries

I see the following strange error if I include any POCO header file in a .mm file or a .h file. If I include the headers in .cpp file then the project successfully compiles. Any help or sample code to make POCO running with objective C project will be appreciable.

Here is the code:

```
//File: test.mm

#import "test.h"    
#include "Poco/JSON/Object.h"

@implementation test
-(void)test{
 Poco::JSON::Object obj;
}
@end
```

Here is the screenshot of the error [image]
[image]

Detailed error:

```
In file included from /Users/a/Desktop/test/theta/theta/test.mm:10:
In file included from /Users/a/Desktop/poco-1.6.0- all/JSON/include/Poco/JSON/Object.h:24:
In file included from /Users/a/Desktop/poco-1.6.0-all/JSON/include/Poco/JSON/Array.h:25:
In file included from /Users/a/Desktop/poco-1.6.0-all/Foundation/include/Poco/Dynamic/Var.h:26:
In file included from /Users/a/Desktop/poco-1.6.0-all/Foundation/include/Poco/Dynamic/VarHolder.h:24:
 In file included from /Users/a/Desktop/poco-1.6.0-all/Foundation/include/Poco/NumberFormatter.h:24:
/Users/a/Desktop/poco-1.6.0-all/Foundation/include/Poco/NumericString.h:261:8: error: expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers
            void check(char* ptr)
            ~~~~ ^
```

Comment: Have you tried uncollapsing the error messages, seeing which file is actually being compiled? Do you have any non-C++ files in your project that include these headers, e.g. .c or .m files?

Comment: The file that throws the error is Foundation/include/Poco/NumericString.h and the project doesn't contain any c or m file that includes any POCO header

Comment: No, source file. The compiler doesn't compile headers, it always compiles source files (and headers in the context of a source file, or "compilation module"). What file hierarchy do you see when you click the triangle next to the first error message. It should show "in file included by" there, and you can collapse a few more times, usually.

Comment: Updated the question with the relevant detail.

Answer (score 3):

ok, the reason for the error is that POCO header is conflicting with one of the header files in the OSX SDK. 
Adding the following line before inclusion of any headers fixed the compilation problem.

```
#undef check
```

Comment: BTW -- you can get Xcode to show you how your code will look after preprocessing by choosing "Preprocess" from the pop-up in the upper left of the text editor pane (the four little connected squares). That would probably have shown you that `check` is defined as sth. else.

Comment: thank you for the solution. After spending long search I finally landed here. Upvoted